# Dual Boot Ubuntu + Win7, Low Graphics Mode, Can't Access Terminal or GRUB

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, graphics

So I successfully installed the latest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 today. At first, there were no issues and everything went smoothly until I had the great idea to change the open-source video drivers for my AMD card to the proprietary ones. Boy what a mistake that was.

Later I restart my PC only to find out Ubuntu boots into low graphics mode. I am unable to see my mouse pointer and none of the keys on my keyboard seem to do anything, apart from showing a little dialogue box in the lower right every now and again ( which also appears to do nothing ).

I have read about a method for fixing this ( http://simpledeveloper.com/system-running-in-low-graphics-mode/ ), yet there is a problem. I can't access the terminal. In fact, I can't even access GRUB to switch back to Win 7. I've tried pressing Shift and Ctrl+Alt+F1 several different ways ( hold down, repeatdly press, etc. ) but none of them did anything. It just boots directly to Ubuntu in low-graphics mode.

I am completely at a loss for what I have to do. I hope you guys can help me out, but I don't think I know what I'm even doing. Can I save this? Or do I have to format the entire HDD and start all over?

Comment: **Update:** I have found a way into the GRUB menu by repeatedly pressing Esc. Curiously, I didn't see an option to boot into Win 7 there. But that's an issue for another time. I have tried failsafeX, and I don't think it did anything. I launched it, it flashed some text on the screen for some milliseconds and then immediately went to a black screen...

Comment: **Update 1:** Great Success! Sort of...
By selecting the first option in the low-graphics menu, I managed to get into the console and follow the instructions in the link above.
However. Ubuntu now seems to be stuck on the loading screen with those 5 orange dots. I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl + Alt + F4 and then Ctrl + Alt + F1.This should get you to console mode.Then you can run the commands provided in the link.Basically Ctrl + Alt + Fn is used to switch to nth text terminal.The below link might be useful

http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie5_1.htm

Comment: Ok, so here's what happened. At some point after I left my PC to idle, a mouse cursor appears on the low-graphics menu. None of the options really helped, apart from "Exit to console login". This brings me to a screen with nothing more than a flashing _ in the upper left corner. It will not accept keyboard input no matter what I try to type.

Also I'm curious when I have to press Ctrl+Alt+Fn.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get into boot options? BIOS or UEFI ? Which system are you using ? Have you installed bootloader for ubuntu in the same place as that for windows ?

Comment: I believe I can, though I haven't tried. I have UEFI. And I have installed Ubuntu on the same HDD as windows, yes. As for system, I don't quite understand what you mean?